# Search ArrayList filled with Objects for specific ID

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm facing the following problem, it´s for a quiz (shuffled answers, not the same amount of answers for every question):

I have two Lists `listOfAnswers` and `listOfUserAnswers` (both are type `List<Answer>`).
`Answer` is defined as followed:

```
public class Answer {

    int     answerId;
    int     answerIsCorrect;
    String  answer;

    public Answer() {

    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.answerId = id;
    }

    public Answer setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;

        return this;
    }

    public void setAnswerIsCorrect(int answerIsCorrect) {
        this.answerIsCorrect = answerIsCorrect;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.answerId;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return this.answer;
    }

    public int getAnswerIsCorrect() {
        return this.answerIsCorrect;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Answer[%s, %s, %s]", this.answerId, this.answerIsCorrect, this.answer);
    }

}
```

The `listOfAnswers` object holds EVERY answer for each question (specified in `listOfQuestions` of type `List<Question>`, but this is not the problem).
The `listOfUserAnswers` object holds every answer, the user has SELECTED (selected by a checkbox). At this point, the app does not know if the answer selected by the user is right or wrong.

Now, when calculating the result, I want iterate through `listOfAnswers` and I check, if the answerId (`listOfAnswers.get(i).getId()`) is also available in `listOfUserAnswers`.

But how does this work? I can't check with `listOfUserAnswers.contains(...)`, I think. Or am I wrong?

Please, comment if you have trouble understanding....

Comment: If you look at the Javadoc for List, it contains the method Object.equals().   Normally by default this compares object ids/addresses.  You need to change this for your circumstance.

Sorry this is homework, I'm not going to actually answer the question for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't check if `listOfUserAnswers.contains()` because you haven't defined an `Answer.equals()` method. You would have to iterate through both lists like so:

```
for(Answer answer : listOfAnswers) {
    for(Answer userAnswer : listOfUserAnswers) {
        if(answer.getId() == userAnswer.getId()) {
            //answer matches
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could define an `Answer.equals()` method:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof Answer && ((Answer)obj).answerId == this.answerId;
}
```

Now instead of a nested loop, you can do:

```
for(Answer answer : listOfAnswers) {
    if(listOfUserAnswers.contains(answer) {
        //answer matches
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** As mentioned in the comments, you should always override `hashCode()` when overriding `equals()`. In this case, the simplest implementation would be:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return answerId;
}
```

Comment: Should override `hashCode` to return `answerId`

Answer (score 1):

To use the ArrayList.contains() method you'll need to override the Object.equals() method. So in this case you'd add to your Answer class something like:

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o instanceof answer){
        return this.answerId == ((Answer) o).answerId;
    } else return false;
}
```

And then you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can, just overwrite equals method as follows:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
          if(!(o instanceof Answer) ) return false;
          return answerId == ((Answer)o).answerId;
    }
```

and call contains.

Comment: This is not safe; you need to check `instanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for `listOfUserAnswers.contains()` is not possible unless you override the following method:

```
@override    
public boolean equals(Object o){
       if(this.answerId == ((Answer)o).answerId ) return true;
       return false;
}
```